# PL/SQL ORACLE triggers

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that when you insert an employee in the company, assign a commission of 0.10 if it is from department 80. This is what I've tried so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER emp_com
BEFORE INSERT ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.DEPARTMENT_ID= '80')
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    :NEW.commission_pct := 0.10;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER emp_com
    BEFORE INSERT ON employees
    FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.DEPARTMENT_ID= '80')    
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING THEN
    :NEW.commission_pct := 0.10;
    END IF;
END;´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger should work fine in its current state; however, the "IF INSERTING" bit is redundant since your trigger only fires for inserts anyway.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER emp_com
BEFORE INSERT ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.DEPARTMENT_ID= '80')
BEGIN
  :NEW.commission_pct := 0.10;
END;
```